# Avoiding blocky output on ffmpeg live stream

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, streaming, video-conversion

I am new to `ffmpeg` and [tvheadend](https://tvheadend.org/). However, I would like to create a live TV stream using `ffmpeg` and `tvheadend`.

From `tvheadend`, I can view the different tv channels - however, they stop working after a while i.e. 10-30 minutes. The stream profiles I use is `webtv-h264-aac-matroska`. `webtv-h264-aac-matroska` allows me to view a channel on chrome by setting the type to `web/mp4` on the native html5 video tag. From the tvheadend logs, I also noticed the warning `[WARNING]:libav: forced frame type (5) at 2159 was changed to frame type (3)`. I wonder whether this could be causing the stop after some time.

As a result, I resorted to using ffmpeg and generate a hls stream using the module [nginx-ts-module](https://github.com/arut/nginx-ts-module). This only works on tvheadend when I use the profile `webtv-h264-aac-mpegts` as the input stream. However, the video generation process is slow and the video gets blocky. At times the audio doesn't work and the video also freezes. The command I use is `ffmpeg -loglevel verbose -i http://localhost:9981/stream/channel/13823d4167df6e44f1a0b7cbf88829a5?profile=webtv-h264-aac-mpegts -c:v copy -c:a copy -f mpegts http://127.0.0.1:8000/publish/sintel`.

Any help?

I just need a way to view the live stream on a browser - whether it comes from tvheadend only or a combination of tvheadend and ffmpeg.